# Convert SQL Query to LINQ in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am new to LINQ and I have this query that I made in SQL

```
DELETE Inscriptions
FROM Inscriptions
INNER JOIN Students on Students.Id = Inscriptions.StudentId
where Inscriptions.StudentId = 149 
 DELETE FROM[dbo].Certifications 
Where StudentId = 149
DELETE FROM[dbo].Students 
WHERE Id = 149
```

How can I convert this to LINQ ?

Comment: This is not a coding service. Please post what you have tried so far as there are thousands of similar questions.

Comment: if you are developer or want be to a good developer then you need to try first. :) happy codding

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. You use it with an ORM to generate queries. If you don't have *entities* you don't need an ORM or LINQ. Besides LINQ is about *querying* where you want to *delete*. Modification functionality is specific to each ORM. If you want help, *forget* about the query *completely*. Define your *entity* classes like, Inscription, Certification, Student, add the appropriate navigation properties and mappings. Once you do, you should be able to delete a Student and have the ORM generate the appropriate deletions

Answer (score 0):

This code will be helpful to you,

```
YourDBDataContext db = new YourDBDataContext();

List<Inscriptions> inList = db.Inscriptions.Join(db.Students, ins => ins.StudentId, 
                            std => std.Id, (ins, std) => new { ins, std }).
                            Where(x => x.ins.StudentId == 149).Select(x => x.ins).ToList();

db.Inscriptions.RemoveRange(inList);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Same coding style can be used for other delete query as well.